# MatDatePicker start week on monday

Tags: angular, angular-material2

There is any way to configure the md-datepicker to start week on monday? By default it start on Sunday and there isn't any specification who to change this.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You have to build a custom `DateAdapter`. A custom DateAdapter is a class which implements the `DateAdapter` interface (it's actually an abstract class that should be extended). It must have a bunch of predefined function implementations and have to be registered as a `useClass` for the `DateAdapter` provider.

```js
providers: [{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter }]
```

The date adapter tells the datepicker things like how to store dates/times internally, how to present them in the input and other things.

Material provided four classes which extends the [`DateAdapter`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/core/datetime/date-adapter.ts) abstract class: [`NativeDateAdapter`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/core/datetime/native-date-adapter.ts), [`MomentDateAdapter`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material-moment-adapter/adapter/moment-date-adapter.ts), [`LuxonDateAdapter`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material-luxon-adapter/adapter/luxon-date-adapter.ts) and [`DateFnsAdapter`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material-date-fns-adapter/adapter/date-fns-adapter.ts). They tell `MatDatepicker` how to work with the javascript native `Date` object and `moment` object, respectively. I'll talk about the javascript native `Date` object, but the same principles apply to any date representation. The javascript `Date` object has some limitations (for example, it's not possible to tell it how do you want to present dates). The long story short: just extends the Material provided `NativeDateAdapter` and override the functions you need. What you want to do is shown in this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tucyvz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-date-adapter.ts) (basically you want to override a function of the `NativeDateAdapter`: `getFirstDayOfWeek : () => number`) and I'll give a little overview afterwards.

```js
getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
  return 1;
}
```

In the demo, you will see a `custom-date-adapter.ts`. This is where you should extended the `NativeDateAdapter`, overriding two functions:

```
1) parse: (value: any) => Date | null
2) getFirstDayOfWeek: ()=> number
```

The first function meant to a) among other things, create a `Date` object from what the user chose in the calendar, and b) parse what is typed in the input to a `Date` object.

The second function (`getFirstDayOfWeek`) tells the calendar to start in a specifc week day (0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday, 2 - Tuesday ...).

Also there's an interesting `format: (date: Date, displayFormat: Object) => string` function available to be implemented/overriden that allows you to define the format the date string must be shown in the input after being selected from the calendar popup.

In the demo, in the main.ts you must tell Angular that there is a custom date adapter to use (look at the providers array). In this case, I built this demo to work with Brazilian Portuguese (look at the main.ts constructor, for the `date.setLocale('pt-BR')`). Over here, we present dates as `dd/MM/yyy`, knowing Monday == "Segunda-Feira" in portuguese. :D

The other pre-built adapter (`MomentDateAdapter`, based on `Moment.js` instead of just the native `Date` object) that, in some cases, saves you from building a custom date adapter, as `Moment.js` already deals with locales in a more efficient way).

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is not working for me. My datepicker is injectable but is never instantiated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65104948/angular-9-how-to-get-extended-locale-aware-start-of-week-nativedateadapter-w

Comment: The code in the link worked for me with two adjustments: had to add override keyword to make the override functions work, and change "getFirstDayOfWeek" to return 1 as the question asked for monday as first day.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, @AsafM. I've updated the stackblitz demo with the `override` decorator.

Answer (score 13):

In case if anyone using `<ngx-mat-datetime-picker>` and wanted to achieve start a week from Monday instead of Sunday.

#### app.module.ts

```js
providers:[{ provide: NgxMatDateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter}]
```

#### custom.date.adapter.ts

```js
import { NgxMatNativeDateAdapter } from '@angular-material-components/datetime-picker';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";


@Injectable()
export class CustomDateAdapter extends NgxMatNativeDateAdapter {
  getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
     return 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the @Injectable() annotation to avoid the future warning.

Answer (score 6):

Based on @julianobrasil https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020144/6052406

Create the class custom-date-adapter.ts to override getFirstDayOfWeek()

```
import { NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';

export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
    override getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

In app.module.ts, import (at least) the following:

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { CustomDateAdapter } from './custom-date-adapter';
import { DateAdapter, MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
```

Add in imports:

```
MatDatepickerModule
MatNativeDateModule
```

Add in providers:

```
providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter }
]
```

Voilá!

Answer (score 5):

If the solution from @julianobrasil doesn't work for someone, you can try this:

If you have multiple sub modules in your project, where one of them uses the Material DatePicker, then make sure that **none** of the SubModules imports the `MatNativeDateModule`. This module provides its own `DateAdapter`, which may overwrite your own `DateAdapter` from `app.module.ts`.

Answer (score 1):

For **luxon-date-adapter** it's simply like:

```js
providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useValue: new LuxonDateAdapter('en-GB', {
        firstDayOfWeek: 1, 
        useUtc: true 
    }) },
]
```

All available options: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material-luxon-adapter/adapter/luxon-date-adapter.ts#L18

Answer (score 0):

It isn't needed to create a class. Only declare de adapter in the constructor and modify the getter:

```
import {Component, Renderer2, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {DateAdapter, provideNativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [provideNativeDateAdapter()],
  imports: [MatCardModule, MatDatepickerModule],
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrl: './calendar.component.scss'
})    

constructor(
    private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>,
    ) {
      this.dateAdapter.getFirstDayOfWeek = () => 1;
    }
```