# how to hide weekend dates in angular material datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material

is it possible to hide the dates saturday/sunday in mat-datepicker.
Or an alternative is rearrange them so it starts with monday

[image: mat date picker]

any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, You can't hide them. However you can make them disabled so that the user can be prevented from selecting any of the weekend dates.

You need to use the `matDatepickerFilter` option to get this done.

In your datepicker-filter.html

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your datepicker-filter.ts have your `myFilter` defined as,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-filter',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-filter.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-filter.css'],
})
export class DatepickerFilter {
  myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    const day = d.getDay();
    // Prevent Saturday and Sunday from being selected.
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ah ok, i stumbled across an answer similar to this earlier , if there is truly no way to hide the weekends then this is most likely the best solution.

Comment: Thank you David ! If you use Moment, you'll get a Moment Object rather than a Date one. You'll need to replace .getDay() by .isoWeekday(). The index for saturday and sunday are 6 and 7.

Comment: @BenoîtPlâtre Ah. I didn't know that mate. Thanks for the enlightment! :-)

Comment: very nice and helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yes it is!

To let it start on Monday (or any other day) I'll refer you to this: [MatDatePicker start week on monday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019317/matdatepicker-start-week-on-monday)

But the real question is: how to hide them?

Simply put: add a custom class to specific dates.

In your component file:

```
@ViewChild("calendar", { static: false }) calendar: MatCalendar<Date>;

hideWeekends() {
    return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
        return this.calendar?.currentView === "month" && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6) ? 'weekend' : '';
    };
}
```

This function will be called on every date in the current view. In previous versions it appears this didn't run for the multi-year and year view, but in the current version it does, so you need to put a check to only do it for the month view. Otherwise years and months starting on Saturday/Sunday will be hidden as well in those other views. Other than that: it's just "apply the class to the 0th (Sunday) and 6th (Saturday) day of the week".

In your html:

```
<mat-calendar #calendar [dateClass]="hideWeekends()"></mat-calendar>
```

In your css:

```
.mat-calendar-table-header th:not(.mat-calendar-table-header-divider):first-child,
.mat-calendar-table-header th:not(.mat-calendar-table-header-divider):last-child,
.mat-calendar-body-cell.weekend {
    display: none;
}
```

Hide the first and last column of the header (but not if it has the divider class), and all the cells that have the custom class.

If you did make a custom DateAdapter and the weekend is the last two columns you could alternatively do this for the header:

```
.mat-calendar-table-header th:not(.mat-calendar-table-header-divider):nth-last-child(-n+2)
```

Here's a full Stackblitz (the css doesn't get applied, but you can inspect the cells and see that the class is indeed applied, so it will work in your project): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v12-rc-view-engine-14dwqp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmatcalendar.ts

[image: Example of mine]

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input matInput [matDatepicker]="lastdatepicker" 
   [matDatepickerFilter]="weekendsDatesFilter" [min]="minlastDateOfProposedTrading" 
  [max]="lastDateOfProposedTradingDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" 
  formControlName="lastDateOfProposedTrading" required/>
           
weekendsDatesFilter = (d: any):boolean => {
const day = d.getDay();
return day !== 0 && day !== 6 ;    
}
```