# Angular 9 - how to get extended (Locale aware start of week) NativeDateAdapter working?

Tags: angular, angular-material

To get a Locale aware (in regards of start of the week) Material DatePicker i created this extension:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { LOCALE_ID, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { Platform } from "@angular/cdk/platform";
import { getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek } from "@angular/common";
import { NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class LocaleDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale: string) {
    super(locale, new Platform());
  }

  getFirstDayOfWeek() {
    return getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek(this.locale);
  }
}
```

I also tried with 0 args constructor and constantly retuning 1 as first day of week. Some colleague told that `{providedIn: 'root'}` might help - it did not.

I hooked it in `app.module.ts` as provider:

```
{
  provide: DateAdapter,
  useClass: LocaleDateAdapter
}
```

my DatePicker is set up like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>set date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" (dateChange)="onDateChange($event)" [formControl]=formDate>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker [startAt]="filter.date"  #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

The problem is that my LocaleDateAdapter is not instantiated (Breakpoint not hit) and the start of the week isn't changing - should  change to Monday.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prepared some [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-datepicker-locale?file=src/app/app.module.ts).

I did more or less the same what you did. However the main difference (and I guess thats the problem, why it is not working for you) is, how you provide the `platform`.

The `NativeDateAdapter` needs as second argument the platform id which you can inject by `@Inject(PLATFORM_ID)` This makes sure that the correct platform id is provided by Angular's DI.

```js
export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  constructor(
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId
  ) {
    super(locale, platformId);
  }
```

The implementation of `getFirstDayOfWeek` is fine as you did.

Note: in my example in `AppModule` I'm forcing to use as `LOCALE_ID` the value for Germany, so `de`. You can also override it with e.g. `en-US`. You also need to comment out then `registerLocaleData` or just remove the whole provider. then you should see as first day of the week Sunday.

Why your constructor is not executed is a bit suspicious. My guess here would be that this has something to do with your module structure.

Comment: thanks for the platform hint, and indeed the main problem was that the providers from app.module were not used - at least the one used by DatePicker. Putting provider into other module or directly into component all works fine now.